# Calculate numbers on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im new to jQuery 
If I have list like this:

```
add one
add two
add three
```

How can I calculate these in container `#calculate`.
When

> add one

is clicked it should add 1 to container, when

> add two

is clicked it should show 3 in container and so should be possible to click these endlessly and every time it should multiply number you click to add

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: just manage counter on click.

Comment: "I have a list like this: add one add two add three" - Is this a HTML list, an array, a string etc...?? Then you say that is should "multiply number you click to add" what do you mean by this exactly. Does this mean if I click "add 2" it turns to "add 4" because 2*2 = 4? Then if I click it again it goes to "add 8" ?

Comment: Please elaborate your requirement, or paste the code that you have implemented so far..

Answer (score 1):

Use a global variable, which is initialized to 0.
use `onClick` to call the function you want, in that case `add(num)` and set the counter value to the result div.

```js
var counter = 0;

function add(num){
  counter += num;
  $("#res").html(counter);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res">0</div>
<button onClick="add(1)">Add One</button>
<button onClick="add(2)">Add Two</button>
<button onClick="add(3)">Add Three</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, somehow I added another answer instead of editing :)

Comment: yes and I was confused why you added 2 answers in a question any way, it's ok :D

Answer (score 1):

```js
var TotalAmount = 0;

function btnClick(Param) { 
  TotalAmount += Number(Param);
  console.log(TotalAmount);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btnOne" onclick="btnClick(1)">Add one</button>
<button id="btnTwo" onclick="btnClick(2)">Add two</button>
<button id="btnThree" onclick="btnClick(3)">Add three</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result">0</div>
<button value="1" onClick="sum(this.value)">Add One</button>
<button value="2" onClick="sum(this.value)">Add Two</button>
<button value="3" onClick="sum(this.value)">Add Three</button>
<script>
var total = 0;
function sum(num){
  total += parseInt(num);
  $("#result").html(total);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div>
   Result: <span id="result"></span><br />
   Number of clicks: <span id="clickNumber"></span><br />
 </div>
 <div>
  <button onclick="addFunction(1)">
   Add One
  </button>
  <button onclick="addFunction(2)">
   Add Two
  </button>
 </div>

 <script>
  let result = 0;
  let clickNumber = 0
  function addFunction(n){
   result += n;
   clickNumber++;
   $("#result").text(result);
   $("#clickNumber").text(clickNumber);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Basically, you will need two global variables which will store your **addition result** and **number of click events made by the end user**. You can have a common **handler function** for addition operation which will receive the value to be added as an argument and in the handler function result will be added by the value and the clickNumber will be incremented by 1 each time the function is called. Lastly you can render those values in view.

Comment: Thanks! Thats perfect

Answer (score 0):

```js
var total = 0;

function add(num){
 if(total==0){
   total += num;
  $("#res").html(total);
  }else{
  total *= num;
  $("#res").html(total);
   }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="res">0</div>
<button onClick="add(1)">Add One</button>
<button onClick="add(2)">Add Two</button>
<button onClick="add(3)">Add Three</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can bind a click event get the text of button to do this as below

```
$("button").click(function(){
    nummber = nummber +( +this.text());
});
```

this you dont need to attach click listner in html add a class to button to find only the calculator button in javascript